# Add Firebase Log Events (Analytics) in dotnet core

Tags: c#, firebase, .net-core, firebase-analytics, google-api-dotnet-client

I have android and iOS mobile mobile applications where am able to use Firebase Log Events(Analytics). The same way need to add some more Event logs from backend using dotnet core. Is there way to use Firebase Log Events(Analytics) in dotnet core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no SDK for working with [Firebase analytics and .net](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=web)

Now this form for Firebase analytics appears to use Google analytics GA4 which means that you could do this your self and go though the measurement protocol  for [GA4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4)

Its just a HTTP Post call

```
POST /mp/collect HTTP/1.1
HOST: www.google-analytics.com
Content-Type: application/json
<payload_data>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! @DalmTo. Where to get "app_instance_id" in c#? For an example:
{
    "app_instance_id": "app_instance_id",
    "events": [{
      "name": "purchase_refund",
      "params": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": "9.99",
        "transaction_id": "ABC-123"
      }
    }]
  }

Comment: i believe app instance id is created by taking the client id add a dot and then the user id so you get "client_id.user_id"

Comment: BTW please let me know if this works.  I haven't had time to try the new firebase analytics.

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with Firebase regarding OTP verification and I achieved it by client side scripting i.e. Adding Firebase in a JS file and adding it into my razor views. So in my perspective Firebase does not provide any support for dotNet for most of its tools. You can make a way around by using JS and add it into your views. If you need to save analytics into your Db or you want to process it, make an API endpoint which will  help you to achieve that.